# ¿Tiene algún nombre la siesta que se hace antes del almuerzo?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

Algunas veces, durante las vacaciones de verano, a mi mujer le gusta echarse una siesta antes de comer, la cual yo llamo jocosamente la "presiesta". ¿Hay algún término o expresión para denominar a esta siesta?

Comment: Yo la llamo _siesta preventiva_: la hago por si acaso luego no puedo hacerla :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se denomina la *siesta del carnero*, tal y como viene recogido en el DLE desde 1925:

> [**siesta del carnero**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XqAH1g9#5jW59df)
>
> 1. f. siesta que se duerme antes de la comida del mediodía.

Hay algunos casos en el CORDE de esta expresión, como el que sigue:

> *Sobre los dos asnos [...] tres niños gitanos duermen la siesta del carnero —la siesta en ayunas—, en postura de muerto en accidente, en cueros vivos y de color petaca, con el vientre hinchado, la frente abombada, la piel reseca.*
>
> Camilo José Cela, "Judíos, moros y cristianos", 1956 (España).

Y de forma indirecta en este otro texto mucho más antiguo:

> *Llegó, al fin, atravesando una foresta,
>
>   al pie de un monte en una fuente clara,
>
>   a la hora en que el carnero tiene siesta,
>
>   en fresca cueva o en la sombra cara [...]*
>
> Jerónimo de Urrea, "Traducción de 'Orlando furioso' de Ludovico Ariosto", 1549 (España).

[El blog de Alfred López](https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/la-curiosa-y-reparadora-siesta-del-carnero/) nos da más detalles:

> [...] es común llamarla de otros modos como siesta del *borrego, del burro, del gorrino, del perro*... (y así con infinidad de animales, ya que parece ser que estos suelen tener la costumbre de dormir antes de comer). Parece ser que la más famosa es la del carnero ya que era muy habitual hacerla entre los pastores cuando sacaban a pastar a sus carneros, quedando sentados a la sombra de un árbol y aprovechando para descansar un rato antes de ponerse a comer.
>
> También podemos encontrar que es llamada ‘siesta canóniga’ o ‘siesta del canónigo’, debido a que era frecuente que estos eclesiásticos echaran una cabezadita disimuladamente durante los rezos que se realizaban al mediodía.

Comment: Mi madre (de un pueblo de Badajoz) la llama «la siesta del burro».

Comment: Llegue aqui via https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2883/nominaciones-a-la-mejor-respuesta-best-answer-nominations-2018-q1  muy buena pregunta y mejor respuesta. Tangencialmente relacionada, en Mexico llamamos a la siesta y/o somnolencia que se apodera de uno ***despues*** de consumir los sacrosantos alimentos como ***mal del puerco*** uno de los modismos mas jocosos y poco finos que conozco, no obstante su uso es casi universal; desde las  familias formadas en el manual de Carreño hasta los ambientes mas humildes