# ¿Por qué "con sus once de oveja" da a entender que alguien se entremete en lo que no le toca?

Tags: etimología, historia, locuciones, animales, números

En el Diccionario de la Lengua Española, en el artículo [**once**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=R3aRnep), se recoge la locución:

> **con sus once de oveja**
> 1. loc. adv. coloq. desus. Era u. para dar a entender que alguien se entremete en lo que no le toca.

He visto que ya aparece en el Diccionario de Autoridades (1737) con el mismo significado.
En el CORDE apenas he encontrado media docena de veces, todos de textos de principios del siglo XVI.

¿Cómo se originó esa locución? ¿Por qué **once** y por qué **de oveja**?

Comment: pregunta para la comunidad (tal vez para el meta) ¿Este tipo de preguntas tienen alguna utilidad en el SE?

Comment: Anda, no sabía que se acepta también _entremeter_. Siempre he dicho _entrometer_.

Comment: @Mike yo creo que sí: se está dando explicación a una locución que, pese a ser algo rebuscada, a alguien le interesará.

Comment: @fedorqui la cuestión es que Mike pregunta por la utilidad. Desde luego a mí todas estas preguntas de etimología y origen de expresiones me resultan muy interesantes y de hecho me encantan, aunque su utilidad sea únicamente satisfacer mi curiosidad. Si hablamos de utildad en el sentido de que me va a servir para algo en mi vida cotidiana, pues ahí ya no sé.

Comment: @Charlie claro, claro, lo mismo pienso. Y de hecho muchas de mis preguntas van también en esta línea, curiosidades más que utilidades.

Comment: tal vez podríamos añadir un tag como "Histórico" ?, tal vez de esta manera podríamos hacer un buen almanaque de términos historicos y evolucion del español

Comment: @Mike: De hecho ya existe la etiqueta **historia** para "Historia o evolución del lenguaje." Por ejemplo, tu pregunta **¿Cuándo fue la palabra "item" agregada al DLE?** tiene "historia" como única etiqueta!

Comment: No sé en términos de utilidad, pero ¡por supuesto que tiene interés! Y suscribo totalmente lo que dice @Charlie.

Answer (score 2):

José María Sbarbi y Osuna (en una obra de 1877) da esta explicación:

> <sup>814</sup> *con sus once de oveja:* «dar a entender que alguno se entromete en lo que no le toca, o en lo que no es llamado ni solicitado» (*Aut.*). Sbarbi (1877: 99) define el uso de esta frase mediante su uso en Andalucía, «persona que se da a entender mansedumbre y humildad fingida», para ello **se basa en el número de letras —once— de la palabra *mansedumbre*.** Este mismo autor da una explicación numérica similar para las frases *estar en sus trece*, con base en las trece letras de *determinación*:
>
> > «y estábase en sus trece diciendo que, si le hacían, habían de ir rocín y manzanas con todos los diablos» (p. 58)
>
> y *echarlo a doce*, doce letras de *desbarajuste*:
>
> > «El licenciado, que vio la barahúnda, echolo a doce» (p. 61).
>
> - [*Retórica y agudeza en la prosa satírico-burlesca de Quevedo*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=d429vzb-qMkC&pg=PA250&lpg=PA250&dq=%22con+sus+once+de+oveja%22),
>   Enrique Martínez Bogo (p.251, nota de pie 814)

La parte relevante de la obra de Sbarbi está aquí:

> Ahora bien: ¿qué significación misteriosa se esconde en estos guarismos? Porque al crear el pueblo en su vasta fantasía esas expresiones, en algo se habrá fundado. El pueblo, ¡ah! si, el pueblo, cuya tendencia se inclina hacia lo maravilloso; el pueblo, siempre amigo de producirse por medio de metáforas y alusiones..., ¿por qué no habrá legado a la posteridad, juntamente con estas bellas concepciones, el principio a que debieran su ser? Pero ni él, ni los eruditos aficionados a recoger sus inspiraciones, nos han dicho nada acerca del particular. Por tanto, ¿sería presunción temeraria en nosotros intentar descorrer el velo del enigma para ver en las locuciones susodichas cierta **alusión a una palabra compuesta de tantas letras cuantas indica el guarismo especial que forma la frase,** y decir que [...]
>
> ***presentarse con sus* ONCE *de oveja* lo hace aquél que manifiesta en su porte la**
>
> `m     a   n   s   e   d   u   m   b   r   e`
> `(1,   2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10, 11.)`
>
> **propia de semejante animal;**
>
> - [*Monografía sobre los refranes, adagios y proverbios castellanos y las obras o fragmentos que expresamente tratan de ellos en nuestra lengua*](http://www.cervantesvirtual.com/s3/BVMC_OBRAS/fef/aaf/0a8/2b1/11d/fac/c70/021/85c/e60/64/mimes/fefaaf0a-82b1-11df-acc7-002185ce6064_4.html),
>   José María Sbarbi y Osuna (1877)

Comment: Esta respuesta me parece muy buena y de hecho la he votado, pero por algún motivo aún me resisto a creerme que tanto la expresión para _once de oveja_ como la de _seguir en sus trece_ hagan referencia al número de letras de determinadas palabras. Ojalá hubiera algún otro texto que lo corroborara de forma independiente.

Comment: Curioso que leyendo el texto de Sbarbi ahora me doy cuenta de que tener la cabeza a las TRES es tenerla _ida_, y que tomar las ONCE es beber _aguardiente_. Pero sigo sin relacionar del todo la "mansedumbre" con ser un entrometido.

Comment: ¿Y dónde se explica la parte de entrometido? ¿cómo un origen numérico justifica el significado? Muy interesante pero no me parece que responda a lo que se pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

La explicación de Sbarbi mencionada en [la respuesta de ukemi](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/27149/12637) me parece cuanto menos genial, dado que de un plumazo te explica el origen de varias expresiones que hacen referencia a números, como "estar en sus trece" (que ya sabemos que en realidad [su origen es distinto](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/27822/12637)), "tener la cabeza a las tres", "tomar las once" y más. Sin embargo, no acabo de ver la relación entre la "mansedumbre", que sería la palabra de once letras a la que hace alusión el dicho, y el ser un entrometido.

La expresión la recoge el *Diccionario de Autoridades* en el siglo XVIII, pero hay registros desde mucho antes. Gonzalo de Correas recoge el refrán en su *Vocabulario de refranes y frases proverbiales* de 1627, tal que así:

> Konke venía la viexa kon sus onze de ovexa.

Y aclara que era una frase usada con desdén: "ya viene con sus once de oveja". Sin embargo, la frase también es usada con otro significado en una obra ligeramente anterior:

> *El día siguiente, que no tenía otro nuevo patrimonio adquirido ni heredado, estábame, como dicen, en mis once de oveja, que es con mi misma necesidad.*
>
> Gregorio González, "El guitón Onofre", 1606 (España).

La edición consultada tiene una nota a pie de página que indica que "en mis once de oveja" en el texto significa "sin provecho". Es decir, que el personaje estaba ocioso, sin nada que hacer, y esto sí me cuadra más con relacionar "once" con las once letrás de "mansedumbre".

Pero claro, revisando el *Fichero general* de la RAE (buscando la palabra "once" y rebuscando entre las más de 300 fichas) descubro que hay quien debate el origen de algunas expresiones numéricas, como la de "tomar las once", argumentando que "las once" no se refiere a las once letras de "aguardiente", sino al aperitivo que se tomaba a las once, y por tanto el número hace referencia a la hora. Así pues, no sería de extrañar que en el caso de "once de oveja" el origen fuera distinto también.

Así que voy a proponer una nueva teoría. Recuerdo que hace tiempo [descubrí la expresión](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/24415/12637) "siesta del carnero", que hace referencia a la costumbre de descansar estos antes de la comida del mediodía. Hay referencias desde el siglo XVI a este momento que tienen los carneros para sestear. Luego si con "once" nos referimos al refrigerio de las once (antes del mediodía), ¿no sería posible que "las once de oveja" se refiera al momento de descanso (ocioso) de las ovejas a esa misma hora? Esto explicaría el origen de la expresión tal y como se recoje en el texto de Gregorio González (en su acepción de "sin provecho"). Y de ahí no es raro que la expresión pasara a hacer mención a las personas que, por no tener una ocupación, se dedican a entrometerse en las ocupaciones de los demás.

Lamentablemente no dispongo de pruebas que lo demuestren. Simplemente me pareció una forma más razonable de explicar el origen que la de hacer cuentas con las letras de determinadas palabras.

Quevedo usó esta expresión en alguna de sus obras. En una nota a pie de página en una de estas se lee:

> Se usa para dar a entender que alguno se entromete en lo que no le importa. Atribuye tal significado la Academia a esta frase, pero el sentido en nuestro autor es más conforme al general en Andalucía, dándose a entender mansedumbre y humildad fingida. Ni en una ni en otra aplicación es fácil averiguar su origen.