# How can you say "Mind your own business" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, expresiones, solicitud-de-modismo

I found a funny tweet saying...

> —Tus traducciones son demasiado literales.
>   —Mente tu propio negocio.
>
> <sub>[Andrés Diplotti, 9 Sept 2018](https://twitter.com/adiplotti/status/1038786270711951360)</sub>

For those who, like me, do not get it immediately, the joke likes in the literal translation of *Mind your own business* that the person in the dialogue is using.

Then I started thinking: how can you say in Spanish the expression *Mind your own business*? Is there any equivalent (not that much literal)?

I was thinking of:

- Ocúpate de tus asuntos

But it may sound rather harsh, I don't know if on the same level of the English one.

Comment: You translation is fine. It is harsh in both languages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**"Ocúpese de sus asuntos"** sounds good to me. Yes, it sounds harsh but "mind your own business" is also harsh.

Alternatively you can say:

- Preocúpese por lo suyo (y déjeme a mi con lo mio)
- No se meta en mis asuntos.
- Zapatero a tus zapatos

In Colombia we have a few ways to say it. Some are:

> No se meta en lo que no le importa
>
> Deje de ser metido.
>
> [Éntrese Miguelito/Jesusita](https://books.google.com.co/books?id=AgLYDeAjFxkC&pg=PA98&lpg=PA98&dq=entrese%20que%20se%20moja&source=bl&ots=DHEDVZxflr&sig=H1-AC9iXrzcF2lHkJW3s39J8XNc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiGloW40LXdAhWMtVkKHdWmCdAQ6AEwB3oECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=entrese%20que%20se%20moja&f=false)
>
> Éntrese que se moja.
>
> Metido-sopero. Deje de ser [sopero](http://www.tubabel.com/definicion/14585).
>
> No busque lo que no se le perdió

In any case, the tone used will determined the harshness degree. All this expression are a bit rude but the tone could change them from funny to extremely disrespectful.

Comment: "Zapatero a tus zapatos!"

Comment: @enxaneta excelente. Lo incorporé en la respuesta. Gracias.

Comment: @DGaleano También añadí una que se me ocurrió gracias al de *zapatero a tus zapatos*.

Answer (score 4):

These are a few:

> —Métete en tus propios asuntos. (Informal.)
>   —Métete en lo tuyo. (Offensive.)
>   —No hay que meterse en donde a uno no lo llaman. (Polite.)
>   —Pastelero a tus pasteles. (Colloquial in Chile.)

On one level, many of these may be expressed with other words, so I wouldn't bank on these ones as being a unique way of saying them; on another level, we must bear in mind that, depending on the situation, these may sound rude to whom we are talking.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say

> Tú a lo tuyo.

or

> Usted a lo suyo.

Depending on the formality. There's also one idiom which is

> Nadie te ha dado vela en este entierro / Nadie le ha dado vela en este entierro.

Answer (score 1):

`[...]  it may sound rather harsh, I don't know if on the same level of the English one.`

If you are looking for something that sounds harsh, I would propose

> y a ti qué te importa?
>
> no te metas donde no te llaman

If you are looking for something more polite

> Eso no es de tu/su incumbencia
>
> No te/le incumbe

which is basically a different way of saying

> Eso no es asunto tuyo/suyo

Also, you could use

> Por favor, no se meta en asuntos ajenos/ no te metas en asuntos ajenos
>
> Ocúpese de sus propios asuntos

Answer (score 1):

Una versión rebuscada para indicar lo mismo es la expresión "con sus once de oveja"

> [con sus once de oveja](http://dle.rae.es/?id=R3aRnep)
>
> 1. loc. adv. coloq. desus. Era u. para dar a entender que alguien se entremete en lo que no le toca.

que una recompensa en una de nuestras preguntas existentes ([¿Por qué “con sus once de oveja” da a entender que alguien se entremete en lo que no le toca?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/27146/5481)) ha destacado recientemente.

Así, la conversación quedaría como:

> —Tus traducciones son demasiado literales.
>
> —Ya estás con tus once de oveja. (ya te estás entrometiendo)

Comment: ¡Qué curiosa está expresión! Nunca la había oído, pero gracias a vosotros he ampliado mis conocimientos. ¡Muchas gracias por ello!

Answer (score 1):

Otra forma, que aunque es muy coloquial, es lo que parece indicar el contexto de la conversación:

> —¡Tú dedícate a lo tuyo!