# ¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "estar alguien en sus trece"?

Tags: expresiones, historia

Como vimos en [esta respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/27149/12637), Sbarbi nos explica el origen de la expresión "estar alguien en sus trece", que significa:

> [**estarse**, **mantenerse**, o **seguir**, alguien **en** sus **trece**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aYPXdWU)
>
> 1. locs. verbs. Persistir con pertinacia en algo que ha aprendido o empezado a ejecutar.
> 2. locs. verbs. Mantener a todo trance su opinión.

Dicho origen estaría basado, al igual que otras expresiones similares que usan números, en el número de letras que tiene la palabra *determinación*, que es lo que muestran las personas que se mantienen en sus trece.

Al igual que me pasó con la expresión "con sus once de oveja", me resisto a creer este origen. Buscando información sobre la expresión encuentro que ya se usaba en *La Celestina*, escrita por Fernando de Rojas alrededor del año 1500:

> *¡En sus treze está este necio!*

Sin embargo, también antigua es la palabra *determinación*, dado que ya aparece en el diccionario de Nebrija de 1495. Por tanto, la explicación de Sbarbi sigue siendo plausible. Y más teniendo en cuenta que, según este ejemplo, "trece" hace alusión a algo femenino (como "letras"):

> *El camarero le dyxo: "Señor, aun estás en vuestras treze."*
>
> Anónimo, "La corónica de Adramón", c1492 (España).

La palabra *trece* tiene de por sí otras implicaciones, desde la religiosa (Jesucristo y los doce apóstoles sumaban trece) hasta más terrenales. Según el *Diccionario de autoridades*:

> TRECE. En el Orden, y Caballería de Santiago, se llama el Caballero Diputado, y nombrado por el Maestre, y demás Caballeros, para algun Capítulo general. Diósele estre nombre, porque siempre eligen trece Caballeros à este fin.

Ejemplo:

> *[...] e aun por la grand distançia de algunos caualleros fué acordado que non se fiziese la congregaçión o ayuntamiento en la dicha villa de Ocaña, saluo que cada uno de los Treze diese su voto para ello en doquier que estouiese.*
>
> Anónimo, "Lope de Estúñiga acepta el cargo de Administrador de la Orden de Santiago", 1465 (España).

Se me haría más plausible que el origen de la expresión estuviera en uno de estos ámbitos. Así pues, ¿existe alguna otra explicación acerca del origen de la expresión "estarse en sus trece" aparte de la propuesta por Sbarbi?

Answer (score 3):

De acuerdo al [blog de 20 minutos](https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/el-tozudo-papa-que-dio-origen-a-la-expresion-estar-en-sus-trece/) "El origen de este dicho procede del Papa Benedicto XIII" cuyo "nombramiento chocaba de pleno con aquellos que reconocían a Bonifacio IX como *Papa legítimo*"

El Papa Luna (Benedicto XIII) **fue elegido pontífice en 1394** en medio de una serie de luchas y ambiciones internas de varios países por conseguir que la sede papal volviese al Vaticano (en 1309 se había trasladada a Aviñón en el conocido como Cisma de Occidente.

> Francia retiró el apoyo a Benedicto XIII, y con ello la sede episcopal de Aviñón, el Papa Luna [Benedicto XIII] se trasladó a vivir al Castillo de Peñíscola, donde siguió manteniéndose en su puesto de pontífice, a pesar de recibir todo tipo de presiones para que renunciara, lo que provocó que rápidamente se comenzase a utilizar, refiriéndose a él, la expresión «sigue en sus trece». **Evidentemente ese trece era una clara referencia al número que acompañaba su nombre papal: XIII**

Esta curiosidad que forma parte del libro “Ya está el listo que todo lo sabe” (Una curiosidad para cada día del año) de Alfred López.

[Etimologías de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/Expresiones/?Mantenerse-en-sus-trece) propone la misma etimología para la expresión, al igual que otros blogs/web como [Historias de la Historia](http://historiasdelahistoria.com/2014/03/21/mantenerse-en-sus-trece) y [Verne/El País](https://verne.elpais.com/verne/2016/10/13/articulo/1476354711_200357.html).

Así que parece que todo esto ocurrió casi un siglo antes que esas entrada de "La corónica de Adramón" (1492) y "La Celestina" (1500) que citas en la pregunta, por lo que los números cuadran.